# Join WHERE clause - table has row with defined value, or no entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me figure out the correct WHERE clause for the following scenario:

```
select A.name
from tableA A, tableB B
where A.id = B.id
and 
(
    B.field = 5
    OR
    B.hasNoRowForJoinedID
)
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here in how to accomplish this, but I can't for the life of me put my finger on it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify the question.  You should learn what the difference is between Brian's and Giorgi's answers, so you can understand why the question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an outdated SQL Syntax.  To perform the LEFT OUTER JOIN based your your request above, you can do the following:

```
SELECT A.name
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE (B.field = 5 OR B.field IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper `join` syntax and not the outdated ones:

```
select A.name
from tableA A 
left join tableB B on A.id = B.id and B.field = 5
```

Comment: Would using that approach give me the entries from A which have no corresponding entry in B?

Comment: @Strongo, yes because of left joining

Comment: For more on JOINs see MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx.